# How to pin to start menu using a batch file (Windows 10)

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I need to pin an executable into the new Windows 10 start menu (i.e. creating a tile).

I'm aware of PowerShell scripts that do the job, but I need some instructions to add at the end of an existing batch file (cmd) we already use for installing our applications.

The usual scripts (valid for Windows 8 and 8.1) simply don't work. How can I do this?

Comment: There are [lots of similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=run+a+PowerShell+script+from+a+batch+file). You should specify why those solutions don't apply in your case, otherwise the question will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Could you point me to one? Those for Windows 8.1 simply don't work.

Comment: Could you please point me to one? Those for Windows 8 simply don't work as well as those for Windows 7. As I said i DON'T want powershell scripts, just a plain command script, if feasible.

Comment: 1. It'd be better if you add this information to the question. 2. I don't have Windows 10 so I can't help you, sorry. 3. Isn't it okay to add `powershell -c "some commands"` to the end of your batch file? (Don't answer here, edit the question accordingly)

Comment: @user5232147 - finally I've reached an windows 10 machine where I was able to test and improve the script.Could download it again and retest  - in case you still need this.

Answer (score 27):

This is a kludge work around that Microsoft needs to fix, but it worked for me.

Temporary rename the .bat file to .exe. Then right click on the file name. It will give you the *Pin to start* option. Pin it to the start menu. It won't work, but there is an option open the file location. Select that and change the name back to .bat. Now it works.

Comment: The question is about how to add an existing EXE file (not a batch one) to new hybrid WIndows 10 menu by using a CMD file. Acting at the console the operation is quite simple: right click on the EXE and choose "Add to start menu" from the context drop-down menu. But couldn't find a way to do the same programmatically.

Answer (score 14):

The way it works on Windows 10 after trying almost 15 different methods that didn't work for me

1. Go to your desktop -> right-click -> *Create New Shortcut*
2. In the shortcut target type the following text:

   ```
    cmd /c "full path to your batch file"
   ```

   It will look something like this:

   ```
   cmd /c "C:\Users\Jmeter\Desktop\jmeter.bat"
   ```
3. Name the shortcut.
4. Right-click on the shortcut -> select *Pin to taskbar*. If you'd prefer it pinned to your Start menu, select *Pin to start* instead.

Bonus: Download some .png image -> Go here (https://icoconvert.com/) -> convert to Windows icon file -> set as new icon

Answer (score 6):

**Note**: I've wrote and tested this on windows 8 - you might face issues on windows 10.

Check [***this***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/pinnerJS.bat). This a JScript/bat hybrid that uses the shellapplication object and invokeverb function (i.e. emulates right click and chooses some specific actions). It is now compatible with Windows 10.

Use it like this (you can use also a shortcut/.lnk to an exe):

```
call pinnerJS.bat "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" startmenu
```

Comment: This is a very useful script. I tested it, and it works really well for Windows 10.

Comment: @markj  I tried it for .lnk and .url file. But it was not working for me . Could you please help ? :(

Comment: Well, having now tried it with newer versions (updates) of Windows 10, it seems like it doesn't work with all links anymore. But I haven't tested it that much lately, so that's all I know.

Comment: This works for pinning EXE files to the start menu or taskbar, but does **not work for CMD, BAT or LNK files**, at least not with the current Windows 10. Since you can right click any EXE to pin it, there's no point in this at all.

Comment: `shellapplication`? Do you mean `shell.application`?

Comment: Hello from 2020, emphasizing: Works **only for some files**, e g system files work fine (like the cmd example), but cannot get it to work for other .exe or .lnk's. No error message, just no result. Have tried different workarounds addressing permissions, etc, with no success so far.

Comment: @MarcusWiderberg - Thanks for the note. I've wrote/tested this on windows 8. They've changed some things in windows 10 and at the moment I haven't invested time to see how to make it work without issue on windows 10. At the moment only thing I can do is a note also in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Follow my original method, and you will get .bat file{s} pinned in Taskbar. WORKS 100%

Step 1: Create shortcut of your .bat file (for example in Desktop “C:\Users\youruser\Desktop\yourfile.bat”). So you will end up with “yourfile.bat – Shortcut.lnk” (you might not see extension “.lnk”).

Step 2: Right Click your shortcut and change your Target field from: “C:\Users\youruser\Desktop\yourfile.bat” to: explorer “C:\Users\youruser\Desktop\yourfile.bat” – note: explorer is the explorer.exe app. You can also write the full Path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe, for no confusion.

Step 3: Now Right Click your shortcut and now you can see the option Pin to Taskbar.

Step 4: Right Click the pinned shortcut, and you will see two options: shortcut itself and unpin option. Right Click the shortcut and select Properties. From Target field delete “C:\Windows\explorer.exe” and leave only “C:\Users\youruser\Desktop\yourfile.bat”, and click OK

Now you can delete your shortcut in Desktop, since now you have your standalone shortcut on Taskbar
Optionaly, if you want to change Icon do Step 4, but now click “Change Icon…” button, and choose your custom Icon, from some other exe file or .ico file.

That’s it!
Now you have fully functional batch file shortcut on Taskbar

Comment: This is a programming site, and the question specifically uses the [[tag:batch-file]] tag. It is unlikely therefore that the OP requires an end user has to perform interative right-click mouse actions and manual string modifications. Whilst a batch file is technically an executable file, the question also implies directly pinning one, as opposed toinvoking one indirectly via a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you can't do this with free tools (maybe Windows want to get into the "pay2tile" business model).

One possible option at the moment would be to use [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/).

Comment: Sure, but how? Must be something OS native,  a shell script or a console batch. Something that can be easily included into an installer.